# intellij http client is non functional even though it is installed

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

have the plugin succesfully installed as evidenced here
[image]

But don't get http file option when attempting to create new file, thus can't make http requests with intellij - LAME
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the plugin is enabled: [image: http client bundled plugin IntelliJ IDEA]